# Weakly labelled dataset for object detection

Tags: tensorflow

I have a few datasets that are well labeled for each class they represent. I'm trying to build an object detection model using the tensorflow/research/object_detection pipeline to detect each object.

However... each dataset is not labelled for the other classes. I'm concerned that mined examples will be labelled as the background class when they really represent a class in the other datasets.

For example, if I'm trying to make a fruit detector and I have a dataset labelled with apples, another labelled with oranges and another labelled with bananas - how would I go about weighting the classification loss so it ignores the apple predictions on the orange examples and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your post correctly, each image has multiple class objects in it. If thats the case then just create multiple bounding boxes for each of the classes  in that image. An image can have multiple bounding boxes drawn with labelled class name that can be used for training

Comment: Yes. I have one dataset that has all three labeled, but without a lot of variation. The other datasets are well labeled and very large, annotating them would be a very daunting task indeed.